# Ready package for semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning

I need do NER with small train set. I think that the solution will realize with some semi-supervised learning algoritm. Is there any ready packages that will fulfill for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Stanford CoreNLP [1] and OpenNLP [2].

[1] http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

[2] https://opennlp.apache.org/

Comment: Are thем semi-supervised?